# After editing and saving gedit(29705), I get warnings. alerts below

Tags: gedit

** (gedit: 30499): WARNING **: 17: 09: 35.099: Document metadata could not be set: Attribute metadata :: gedit-spell-language assignment not supported

** (gedit: 30499): WARNING **: 17: 09: 35.099: Setting document metadata failed: Attribute metadata :: gedit-encoding assignment not supported

** (gedit: 30499): WARNING **: 17: 09: 39.106: Setting document metadata failed: Attribute metadata :: gedit-position assignment not supported

Comment: Please add more information about what it is that you were doing.

Comment: This is just noise. Exactly what command are you using?